# how can i prove that this grammar is ambiguous?

Tags: grammar

```
S -> bA|aB
A -> a|aS|bAA
B -> b|bS|aBB
```

Any easy method other than trying to find a string that would generate two parse trees ?

Can someone please give me a string that can prove this.

Comment: for me this looks like its unambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy method for proving a context-free grammar ambiguous -- in fact,
[the question is undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar), by reduction to the [Post correspondence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem).

Comment: yeah but i cannot write that on the answer sheet. What attributes of the grammar should i look at to correctly select the string that gives rise to 2 parse trees?

Comment: @user: According to my copy of Hopcroft and Ullman, you should consider the string "aaabbabbba", and find a left derivation, a right derivation, and a parse tree using the grammar you specified. Hopefully, with the solution to exercise 4.8 in hand, the rest will become clear!

Comment: is there a way to come up with a string ?

Comment: @user: There aren't any shortcuts -- basically just generate all possible parse trees and look for two of them that produce the same string. An ambiguous grammar will be eventually detected as such in finite time...an unambiguous grammar, not so much! (Or else the problem would be decidable).  Since Hopcroft and Ullman called out a specific string to look at, there might be something interesting about it.  (Not trying to dance around the solution, I just haven't worked through it.)

Answer (score 18):

There is a string though: `bbaaba`

```
S -> bA -> bbAA -> bbaA -> bbaaS -> bbaabA -> bbaaba
S -> bA -> bbAA -> bbaSA -> bbaaBA -> bbaabA -> bbaaba
```