# How can I show that this grammar is ambiguous?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

I want to prove that this grammar is ambiguous, but I'm not sure how I am supposed to do that. Do I have to use parse trees?

```
  S -> if E then S | if E then S else S | begin S L | print E
  L -> end | ; S L
  E -> i
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _ambiguous_? That there exists a word for which more than one derivation is possible?

Comment: @Codor Yes, there has to be at least one string with more than one parse tree.

Comment: Will something like this `if E1 then if E2 then print S1 else S2` cause two different derivations?

Answer (score 1):

You can show it is ambiguous if you can find a string that parses more than one way:

```
if i then ( if i then print i   else print i ; )
if i then ( if i then print i ) else print i ;
```

This happens to be the classic "[dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else)" ambiguity. Googling your tag(s), title & grammar gives other hits.

However, if you don't happen to guess at an ambiguous string then [googling your tag(s) & title](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> **[how can i prove that this grammar is ambiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4878418/3404097)**
>
> There is no easy method for proving a context-free grammar ambiguous -- in fact,
>   [the question is undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar), by reduction to the [Post correspondence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the grammar into a parser generator which supports all context-free grammars, a context-free general parser generator. Generate the parser, then parse a string which you think is ambiguous and find out by looking at the output of the parser.

A context-free general parser generator generates parsers which produce *all* derivations in polynomial time. Examples of such parser generators include SDF2, Rascal, DMS, Elkhound, ART. There is also a backtracking version of yacc (btyacc) but I don't think it does it in polynomial time. Usually the output is encoded as a graph where alternative trees for sub-sentences are encoded with a nested set of alternative trees.